# How does stackoverflow prevent the tyranny of selfish moderators?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, frustration

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>
> - [What are the rules around moderators closing questions outright?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/855/what-are-the-rules-around-moderators-closing-questions-outright)
> - [When is it acceptable for a moderator to make a unilateral decision to close a question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321/when-is-it-acceptable-for-a-moderator-to-make-a-unilateral-decision-to-close-a-qu)

How does stackoverflow prevent the tyranny of selfish moderators who close questions at will (for instance because they are bureaucratic or have an ego problem)? Closing questions can be very frustrating for powerless newcomers.

Comment: Actually, the mods are not selfish, they enforce the rules as set by the site owner. See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/350/the-six-subjective-question-guidelines-enforcement-notice  You may not like the rules, in fact many members have expressed frustration about that, but currently it's how things are done.

Comment: To add to what ChrisF says here, there are ~150 users on the site who can vote to override a moderator's decision. As a general rule, they *don't*. Anecdotally, SO users seem much more willing to *fight* for a question they think is worthwhile... And by "fight" I mean "argue for it and use the tools the site gives to you achieve your goals" not "make hyperbolic complaints on Meta"... In the last 30 days, *one* question has been re-opened by five users voting. **1**. Either the moderators are doing a really fantastic job, or the community is consumed by apathy - pick the one that appeals to you

Comment: Awesome point. Ironically, @Mark Trapp quit StackExchange in November: https://plus.google.com/app/basic/stream/z12gtfsi0znwgzmjx04ci1d43zels1nbkl40k?cbp=1sh4u3socogpd&spath=/app/basic/107485877062152067451/posts&sparm=cbp%3Dood3222jbnp3%26spath%3D/app/basic/stream%26sparm%3Dcbp%253D11exxswmsbftv%2526sview%253D27%26sview%3D27%26stct%3DCAIQwZH0lveLtAIgCigB&sview=27

Answer (score 8):

There are several checks.

Firstly, any user with more than 3,000 reputation can cast a reopen vote. When 5 people have voted the question is reopened.

Secondly, moderators review each other and they can reverse the decision with a single vote. If there is a particular question you have in mind flag it for moderator attention to speed this along.

Thirdly, you can post a question here on meta raising the issue. This will help with the first two points as well as more people will see the question.

Finally, you can send an e-mail to the team - use the "contact us" link at the foot of every page. Though this should be reserved for the most serious problems.

Comment: I would say the checks fail sometimes. You closed [my question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/86064) which was migrated from Stackoverflow because it is subjective, although [one of your own questions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/779) is very subjective, too. If the question is not about programmers, then what question is? It certainly helps us to be better programmers, and this should be the purpose of the site. Therefore it seemed to me a biased and unjustified decision. Many other uses complain about similar experiences.

Comment: If you are referring to [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/779/whats-the-worst-question-you-were-ever-asked-at-interview), it was asked in the early days of the site before the guidelines were revised.

Comment: @0x4a6f4672 Thanks for bringing that question up. It's hard to find all the old questions that no longer fit the site's guidelines. It has now been closed as it would've been if it were asked today.

Comment: @0x4a6f4672: Which is why if you find a good old question, keep it to yourself. If it comes to the attention of mods they'll kill it.